# Distribution of difference of F distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two random variables distributed according to a F distribution with (almost) the same parameters. What is the distribution of the difference of those random variables? Is it possible to have an analytical formulation of that distribution?

In my case, the random variables come from an F statistic computed on two different set of samples, with parameters 15 and around 800 in both cases (but not exactly the same number).

Comment: Can you become a bit more precise on $F$ and "almost" the same "parameters"?

Comment: I added some precision, I hope it helps

Comment: Let $X$ induce the probability distribution $P_X$ which is uniquely determined by the distribution function $F$ (i.e., what you are  looking for). You can obtain $F$ if the probability density function (pdf) is known. The derivation of the pdf for a general linear combination of Fischer-Snedecor distributed random variables is no joke. If you really need it, then master this: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.611.4389&rep=rep1&type=pdf.

Comment: @CelineHarumi. Interesting link, thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. Could you clarify what is your aim? Are you trying to compare variances? In this case, the two-sample F-test to compare variances is pretty straighforward.